# Compatability error 2003 - 2016 macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, module, runtime-error, office365

Quick query about some VBA. I have recently moved from Excel 2003 to 2016 (365), and there are issues with transferring code.

I have a cell you input a number in. When you press enter after editing the cell, it adds that value to a cell 2 cells to the right, and keeps a tally. It then erases the value in the original cell.

```
Sub CasesChecked()
    If Sheets("Work Return").Range("F13") = "" Then
        Sheets("Work Return").Unprotect "adminstats"
        Sheets("Work Return").Range("F13") = Sheets("Work Return").Range("D13")
        Sheets("Work Return").Range("D13") = ""
        Sheets("Work Return").Protect "adminstats"
    Else
        Sheets("Work Return").Unprotect "adminstats"
        Sheets("Work Return").Range("F13") = Sheets("Work Return").Range("F13") + Sheets("Work Return").Range("D13")
        Sheets("Work Return").Range("D13") = ""
        Sheets("Work Return").Protect "adminstats"
    End If

End Sub
```

The code above is found in Module1, and in Sheet1 there is the code below. This confirms the cell change through an intersect:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("D13")) Is Nothing Then
    CasesChecked
    Else
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("D17")) Is Nothing Then
    CasesChecked2
    Else
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I get the dreaded "run-time error '-2147417848 method range of object _worksheet failed" and can't quite figure out why. The code is simple, I don't know where it falters.

Any advice would be hugely appreciated

Thank you,

Ryan

Comment: Where is ***CasesChecked2*** ??

Comment: My best bet is `Target`. It's declared as a range, and in your code you write `Target.Worksheet.Range("D17"))` which is the same as `Range(some_range).Worksheet.Range("D17"))`. Try to figure out what `Target` is. You can add a breakpoint at the first line and step through the code with F8 if you don't know where the code fails.

Comment: *when* do you get this error and *where*?

Comment: Hi @Gary'sStudent Student - CasesChecked2 is just a carbon copy of CasesChecked, in another sub just below CasesChecked.
Andreas - Thanks for your idea! target worked fine on XP/2003 - it also actually works in this version (the macro runs fine) but once its finished running, it continues to refresh as if stuck in a loop, then throws up the error message.
FunThomas I get the message when the macro has ran, i.e: the cell has changed (A value was typed). The macro completes, it then continues as if it's stuck in a loop that doesn't exist, then crashes out with an error message, user UX issue

Comment: @Andreas please see above comment,. thank you

Comment: @FunThomas also please see above comment reply, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first make this change and try again:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("D13")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            CasesChecked
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
        If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("D17")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                CasesChecked2
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        Else
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

In the original code, `Worksheet_Change()` responded to user-initiated changes.  But it also responded to changes made by `CasesChecked()`.

This created a malicious loop.  The new code avoids this.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm. Thank you very much! Do you mind explaining a little about what you changed, just for my learning

Comment: @CluelessMacroMan  see my **EDIT#1**